# Font-Weight from CSS not taking effect until all P elements on page have been scrolled to

Tags: html, css, loading

So, this is just a basic site layout I've used dozens of times.  Suddenly (ie. today - I haven't made one for anyone in a while) the text CSS isn't instantiating until I've scrolled to all elements using these tags..  I don't get it.  It does seem like the Bootstrap styles are visible, and the font-family is working, but not what I'm changing locally, which is mainly just the font weight to keep it thinner looking.

https://2811market.com/

It's strange, because if you click the link you'll see that it's an issue with all fonts on the page (including the little bit in that splash header) but obviously CSS in general is working because positioning and such are all there.

```
<section id="property-details">
    <div class="container-lg property-details">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <hr class="hr-element icon-home" data-content="&#xf015;">
                <!--                    <p class="listing-address" style="padding-bottom:0;margin-bottom:0;">Valley of the Moon</p>-->
                <!--                    LISTING HEADLINE-->
                <h1 class="listing-headline" style="padding-top:0;">2811 Market Street</h1>
                <!--                    ADDRESS-->
                <p class="listing-address">San Francisco</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="details-h1 text-center">
                    Quintessential Castro Condominium
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" alt="2811 Market Street" src="images/property_images/03_living-1.jpg" style="padding-top:2em;padding-bottom:2em;">
                <p class="lead">
                    Looking for a home befitting your unique way of life? Stop your search.
                </p>
                <p class="lead">
                    2811 Market Street is an oversized, cleverly designed studio in a 1922 Art Deco building in the heart of the Castro. Bathed in light from three sides, this top-floor corner unit is beloved for many reasons in addition to its incredible location: quaint historic features, a large kitchen and dining area, tight-knit building community, and stunning views including the Caselli Mansion to the south and Eureka Valley to the west.
                </p>
                <p class="lead">
                    Period charm abounds here, with hardwood floors and original trim combining to create an unforgettable ambiance. A stunning remodeled kitchen features maple cabinetry and all stainless-steel appliances, providing a perfect environment for culinary experimentation. Add in a private single-car garage, extra basement storage, and an efficient, congenial homeowners’ association and you’ve got an unbeatable package.
                </p>
                <p class="lead">
                    Now let’s talk location. The Castro District is one of the city’s most hotly desired neighborhoods, a longstanding tribute to independence and reclamation of one’s identity. Here you’ll find historic locales such as the Twin Peaks Tavern, a gay bar that made history in 1972 by featuring floor-to-ceiling window rather than hiding patrons in dark corners. You’ll discover all stripes of identity through a variety of cuisines, retail, and entertainment. You’ll love the proximity to Dolores Park as well as transportation. Whether you’re tucking into a hearty meal at Frances or clinking glasses at Blackbird, you’ll know you’ve truly come home.
                </p>
                <p class="details-h1 text-center">
                    Welcome to the Castro
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" alt="2811 Market Street" src="images/property_images/15_twin-peaks.jpg" style="padding-top:2em;padding-bottom:2em;">
                <p class="lead">
                    San Francisco’s landmark Castro District is one of the most highly sought-after neighborhoods. With its proximity to fine and casual dining, parks and recreation, private and public transportation, and easy freeway access – the best of San Francisco awaits you at your doorstep. Neighborhood highlights include SoulCycle, Philz Coffee, Pottery Barn, Mollie Stones and numerous San Francisco boutique shops and restaurants. Enjoy the Eureka Valley Park and Rec Center with a playground, tennis courts, dog park, gymnasium with basketball courts, and large outdoor playing field. Head a few blocks east to the newly renovated Dolores Park with iconic San Francisco views. Enjoy dining at some of San Francisco’s hottest eateries including Michelin Star winning hot spots Frances and The Lark. Complete your evening out at neighborhood wine bars or with the award-winning cocktail mixologists at Blackbird.
                </p>
                <p class="lead">
                    The Castro’s vibrant culture and colorful streetscapes have long been a source of San Francisco PRIDE. Buzzing with life and activity, the Castro’s flamboyant bars and restaurants, glittering shops, and historical theatres comprise its endearingly unapologetic attitude. Although this neighborhood is considered San Francisco’s gay-friendly epicenter, all are invited to experience the Castro’s unabashed zest for life.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

'''

All  I'm really doing is setting font-weight to 100 in the P tag, and all of those styling tags for my various text elements on the page.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  There is also a Scroll Reveal plugin JS that is being used on those elements, but that just affects when they become visible and how they animate.  I also did turn it off (deleted the script tags for it entirely) and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Please add the CSS that reproduces this; using a snippet perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Yeesh.  I don't know how, but I had this as the font I was calling:

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gelasio|Roboto&display=swap');

I was using Roboto as my font family, and I guess that import was taking a long time to load.  No idea.  I switched it to this:

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;1,100&display=swap');

Comment: Try to format your answer correctly, See how do I write a good answer [answer].